# Search for a file in multiple directories in bash

Tags: bash, shell

**I have a structure like this:**

```
basedir -> 187382 -> name1 -> name1.keytab
basedir -> 049328 -> name2 -> name2.keytab
basedir -> 233432 -> name3 -> name3.keytab
basedir -> 234343 -> name4 -> name4.keytab
...
```

The numbers are different and I don't know them.

**In a bash script I want to say:**

`export X="basedir/*/$name/$name.keytab"`

What should I write instead of the star? Or if such a symbol does not exist... how can I search for the $name.keytab in each folder in the basedir?

Comment: What's the value of `X` expected to be?

Comment: sparkYarnKeytab

Comment: Do you *really* need to `export` it, or is a process-local variable good enough?

Comment: Yes,I need export

Comment: What do you want X to actually look like?  Are you hoping to expand it to a colon separated list like `basedir/187382/name1/name1.keytab:basedir/049328/name2...`, or perhaps `basedir/187382,049328,233432,234343/...` or .... ?  It's not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why are you not just doing `find basedir -name '*.keytab'` ?

Comment: Because the .keytab is in one of the directories in basedir...

Comment: And I don’t know the exact names of the folders in basedir so I can’t use “/187382,049328,.../

Answer (score 1):

Expand your glob into an *array*, not a string variable, leaving the `*` unquoted:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[[ $BASH_VERSION ]] || { echo "ERROR: Shell is not bash" >&2; exit 1; }
shopt -s nullglob  # allow a glob to expand to an empty list if nothing matches

keytabs=( "basedir/"*"/$name/$name.keytab" )
case ${#keytabs[@]} in
  0) echo "ERROR: no keytab found for $name" >&2; exit 1;;
  1) true;;
  *) echo "ERROR: ${#keytabs[@]} keytabs found for $name; expected only one" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

# assign the first/only keytab we matched to an exported string variable.
X=${keytabs[0]}; export X

# for debugging purposes, print the definition of X so it's visible that we exported it
declare -p X >&2
```

Comment: So, that means there *is* no file matching `"basedir/"*"/$name/$name.keytab"` (that your current process has permissions to read).

Comment: @Gigi, ...btw, since `basedir/` doesn't start with a `/`, that means your current directory needs to be the one that `basedir` is under. Is that the case here? You might add a `cd /path/to/place/before/basedir || { echo "ERROR: Could not cd to top-level directory" >&2; exit 1; }` somewhere earlier in the script just to be safe.

Comment: BTW, it's very normal for keytabs to be in directories with restrictive permissions -- they're security-sensitive content, after all.